# Is existence of Stream as final co-algebra for the suitable functor enough to write functions into equality of streams by co-induction in ExtMLTT?

Tags: type-theory, equality, coinductive-type, martin-lof-type-theory, extensional-type-theory

Suppose we work inside MLTT with equality reflection (extensional MLTT).
Assume I postulate existence of Streams as final co-algebra for the suitable functor.

Is that enough to prove the bisimulation principle:

```
R : Stream A → Stream A → 
R-head : (xs ys : Stream A) → R xs ys → xs.head ≡ ys.head
R-tail : (xs ys : Stream A) → R xs ys → R xs.tail ys.tail 
---------------------------------------------------------
bisim : (xs ys : Stream A) → R xs ys → xs ≡ ys
```

If not, what extra must be assumed to prove it? Do I need to assume a co-induction principle for `(xs ≡ ys)`? As in assume that `(_ ≡(Stream A) _)` is the final indexed co-algebra or something?

Comment: You almost sound like a student of mine who's currently formalizing this stuff as a class project.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not them. You can tell me the answer, I won’t disclose it to them, I promise 

Comment: The other day the students asked how to derive equality from bisimilarity. The answer given by Danel Ahman was: "You will need a  `postulate` for that." (This was Agda.)

Comment: I believe the standard approach is to consider $Σ_{xs,ys : \mathsf{Stream}_A} R\ xs\ ys$. This can be given a 'simultaneous step' coalgebra structure due to the premises on $R$. Then both projections ($xs$ and $ys$) are coalgebra homomorphisms to $\mathsf{Stream}_A$, so must be equal (by finality). So, did you try that?

Comment: @DanDoel Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 3):

The universal property of final coalgebras can be formalized as

```
unique-ana : ∀ (f : A → B × A) (g : A → Stream B) →
  unfold ∘ g ≡ map₂ g ∘ f → g ≡ ana f
```

where

```
unfold : Stream B → B × Stream B   -- Final coalgebra
ana : (A → B × A) → A → Stream B   -- Anamorphism of a coalgebra
map₂ : (A → S) → B × A → B × S     -- The functor (B ×_)
```

Assuming functional extensionality (which you have in ExtMLTT), `unique-ana` is indeed equivalent to the bisimulation principle, aka. stream extensionality:

```
stream-ext : s ≈ t → s ≡ t
```

where

```
_≈_ : {A : Set} → Stream A → Stream A → Type₁  -- Bisimilarity
s ≈ t = Σ[ R ∈ (Stream _ → Stream _ → Type) ]
  R s t × (∀ {u v} → R u v → (u .hd ≡ v .hd) × R (u .tl) (v .tl)))
```

The trick is to view a stream `s : Stream A` as a coalgebra `index s : ℕ → A × ℕ`, which given an index `i` returns the `i`-th element of `s` and the incremented index `i+1`. Define `drop i s` as the stream after dropping the first `i` elements of `s`. The universal property `unique-ana` tells you that `drop i s = ana (index s) i`. Then `s ≈ t → s ≡ t` can be proved as follows:

```
s
≡ drop 0 s         -- by definition
≡ ana (index s) 0  -- by unique-ana
≡ ana (index t) 0  -- by fun-ext and s ≈ t
≡ drop 0 t         -- by unique-ana
≡ t                -- by definition
```

Note that the bisimulation principle *is* a coinduction principle for the identity type on streams: in your formulation, the premises above the bar is a coalgebra (an object `R` and a morphism `R ~> F R` for a certain endofunctor `F`) and the conclusion is the anamorphism `R ~> _≡_`.