# Co-induction principle

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, inductive-type, coinductive-type

It's known that `Nat-ind = Nat-rec ⨯ Nat-initiality`

Has someone figured out how to define a suitable `Conat-coind`
such that `Conat-coind = Conat-corec ⨯ Conat-finality`?

It it a plausible thing to do?

Do we need some notion of `co-dependent types`?

EDIT:
Here are the definitions of `Nat-ind`, `Nat-rec`, `Nat-initiality`:

```
Nat-ind ≔  (ind : (A : ℕ → ) (a₀ : A 0) (a₁ : (x : ℕ) → A x → A (S x)) (x : ℕ) → A x) 
         ⨯ (ind-0 : (A : ℕ → ) (a₀ : A 0) (a₁ : (x : ℕ) → A x → A (S x)) → ind A a₀ a₁ 0 ≡ a₀)
         ⨯ (ind-1 : (A : ℕ → ) (a₀ : A 0) (a₁ : (x : ℕ) → A x → A (S x)) (x : ℕ) 
                           → 
                    ind A a₀ a₁ (S x) ≡ a₁ x (ind A a₀ a₁ x)
           )
         ⨯ ()

Nat-rec ≔ (rec : (A : ) (a₀ : A) (a₁ : A → A) → (ℕ → A))
        ⨯ (rec-0 : (A : ) (a₀ : A) (a₁ : A → A) → rec A a₀ a₁ 0 ≡ a₀)
        ⨯ (rec-1 : (A : ) (a₀ : A) (a₁ : A → A) (x : ℕ) → rec A a₀ a₁ (S x) ≡ a₁ (rec A a₀ a₁ x))
        ⨯ ()

Nat-initiality : (A : ) (a₀ : A) (a₁ : A → A) (f : ℕ → A) 
                 (f-0 : f 0 ≡ a₀) 
                 (f-1 : (x : ℕ) → f (S x) ≡ a₁ (f x))
                 →
                 f ≡ rec A a₀ a₁
```

By this `Nat-ind = Nat-rec ⨯ Nat-initiality` I, of course, mean isomorphism/equivalence:

`Nat-ind ≃ Nat-rec ⨯ Nat-initiality`

So paraphrasing my original question:
is it possible to come up with such a type `Conat-coind`
(a co-induction principle) such that
`Conat-coind ≃ Conat-corec ⨯ Conat-finality`.
Of course there is the trivial identity-equivalence solution. But that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you define `Nat-rec` and `Nat-ind`? And I think https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/is-existence-of-stream-as-final-co-algebra-for-the-suitable-functor-enough-to-wr answers your question (`corec` is `ana` and `coind` is the bisimulation principle) but since you're the one who asked it I may be misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: I don’t see how bisimulation is a co-induction principle in the sense stated in my question. In your answer you say that unique-ana is equivalent to bisimulation. Or in other words stream-finality is equivalent to bisimulation. A co-induction principle for streams would be equivalent to the product of corec (ana) and finality (unique-ana / bisimulation)

Comment: Nat-rec is the usual recursion principle for Nat. Nat-ind is weak mathematical induction. I’ll define them when I get to a PC.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I edited the question to contain the definitions of `Nat-XXX`

Answer (score 1):

> It it a plausible thing to do?

I could just be lacking imagination, but this doesn't seem like a plausible thing to do. This seems to be a misguided attempt at understanding coinduction by duality with induction. So I'm going to answer this more general question instead:

#### What is the dual of induction?

I will convince you that the answer is indeed that the dual of induction, aka. "coinduction", is the bisimilarity principle, "bisimilarity is equality" (copied below from your previous question):

```
R : Stream A → Stream A → 
R-head : (xs ys : Stream A) → R xs ys → xs.head ≡ ys.head
R-tail : (xs ys : Stream A) → R xs ys → R xs.tail ys.tail 
---------------------------------------------------------
bisim : (xs ys : Stream A) → R xs ys → xs ≡ ys
```

My answer to your previous question gives a weak justification: given a `corec : (A -> B * A) -> A -> Stream B`, the bisimilarity principle is equivalent to the uniqueness of `corec`, like how induction is equivalent to the uniqueness of `rec : (1 + A -> A) -> Nat -> A`.

You did not find that satisfactory because with dependent types, induction also gives you a definition of `rec` (`rec` is just a non-dependent specialization of induction). So you went looking for something similar with coinductive types, i.e., a `coind` with which you can define `corec`. But I think that is asking too much. I can't even begin to imagine what that would look like. I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

At least one particularity that distinguishes the bisimilarity principle and induction among all other equivalent properties is that they don't mention `corec`/`rec`. But beyond that there doesn't seem to be much symmetry between the bisimilarity principle and induction that one usually expects from "duals".

An important idea towards a stronger justification is that types are groupoids. A type should be thought of as not just a set of values, the "equality" relation between values is also part of the structure of a type.
So when you define a type's constructors/destructors, you are also defining constructors/destructors for its equality type (aka. path type).

```
0 : 0 = 0
S : n = m -> S n = S m
rec : R 0 0 -> ((n m : Nat) -> R n m -> R (S n) (S m)) -> (n m : Nat) -> n = m -> R n m
```

For a simple inductive type like `Nat`, the constructors are kinda boring because `0` and `S` are just a roundabout way of spelling out `refl`. `rec` (the non-dependent eliminator for equality on `Nat`) is slightly more interesting: it's just induction, parameterized by a binary predicate instead of a unary predicate! Induction over `Nat` is (a consequence of) recursion over its path type viewed as another inductive type.

Same thing for streams (`hd,` `tl`, `corec`). Equality on `Stream` becomes a coinductive type, whose `corec` is just the bisimilarity principle!

```
hd : x = y -> hd x = hd y
tl : x = y -> tl x = tl y
corec : ((x y : Stream A) -> R x y -> (hd x = hd y) /\ (R (tl x) (tl y))) -> (x y : Stream A) R x y -> x = y
```

There you have it. When types are groupoids:

- Induction is elimination of equality for inductive types.
- Coinduction is introduction of equality for coinductive types.